# Screen Flickering in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics, flicker

It wasn't much of a concern at the time, but now I'm forced to use Ubuntu.

There are periods of time where the screen "flickers". By ''flicker'', I mean something refreshing the screen in Windows desktop about ~ 1-2 times per second, randomly. The periods of flickering are intermitent; although, usually when it starts, it doesn't stops until reboot (login in/out doesn't seems to make a difference).

I've tried basic stuff such as changing the basic screens settings such as it's resolution and refresh rate.

- It happened since I installed Ubuntu 20.04 (about 2 years ago) and was present even in the installation.
- I'm dual-booting with Windows 10 where it doesn't happen.
- I have an external display (desktop monitor) where doesn't happen.

About the system: it's an HP Pavillion-15 cw0xxx with an AMD Ryzen 5 2500U CPU with integrated graphics Radeon Vega 8. Since there are no proprietary graphics drivers from AMD for my processor, I'm using the ones that the SO found.

I'm more than happy to provide any information you may consider
relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, this is because of a unsupported discrete graphics card. I myself have a Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ARR with the processor same as yours and a radeon 540 graphics card. Been finding a solution for this problem forever but I finally found one which was to disable my discrete graphics card.

It isn't a problem for me to disable it since I'm mainly using it for work.

To solve this, you need to go to bios. Under 'Configurations' tab, search for a parameter (for graphics) which has a value of [Discrete]. Then change it to the another option (there should only be two of the 'Discrete' and the other one).

Comment: 1. I don't have a CPU and a GPU, I have an APU. Do you have an APU and a GPU? You are telling me to disable a dedicated graphics card which I don't have (if I had one I wouldn't disable it since I'm dual booting with Windows). 2. My UEFI settings doesn't allow me to disable anything at all.